# Count of rows over a window as a total

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pyspark I am trying to execute a count of all rows within a dataframe.

On Hive, I am able to execute it with:

```
count(1) OVER () as biggest_id
```

However on pyspark, I am unsure how to execute it. Here is what I tried:

```
df_new = (
    df.withColumn('biggest_id', F.count(F.lit(1)).over())  
)
```

Usually the over argument needs a windowing statement, but I haven't been successful on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. None is not allowed but can make the window of all.

```
.over(Window.partitionBy())
```